# UI automator file not included in the latest AndroidStuio or ZIP file with all SDK-tools

Tags: android-sdk-tools

I have been spent 3 days with google and other sites but didn't find an answer on my question.
After installing Android Studio and download the all SDK tool via tools/SDK manager/SDK tools I'm still unable to find file "uiautomatorviewer.bat".
1) At first, I have not a standard path which described on other tutorial sdk/tools, in latest Android Studio new path to *.bt file is here -> C:\Users\Alex**AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin**

2) I tried to installed the SDK tools zip file with all SDK tools, but ZIP file had a folder with the same tools which I had in this path -> **AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin**
apkanalyzer
avdmanager
lint
screenshot2
sdkmanager

3) I also tried to find the uiautomatorviewer manually by using search in paths:
- C:\Users\Alex**AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin**
- C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
But found only the java/jar files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ppa6.png)